# MySQL Select from 3 tables and get attendance In and Out Time for all Members in specific date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three table Like this:

```
members_tbl
id | Fullname | Email | MobileNo

attendance_in_tbl 
id | member_id | DateTimeIN

attendance_out_tbl
id | member_id | DateTime_OUT
```

I want to select all members for date: 2014-03-10 by this query:

```
SELECT
attendance_in.EDatetime,
members_info.mfullname,
attendance_out.ODatetime
FROM
attendance_in
LEFT JOIN members_info ON members_info.id = attendance_in.MemID
LEFT JOIN attendance_out ON attendance_out.MemID = attendance_in.MemID
WHERE date(attendance_in.EDatetime) OR date(attendance_out.ODatetime) = "2014-03-10"
```

But it give me different results in Attendace_out Results

Comment: Here is result duplicated results with different date   http://img4host.net/viewer.php?img=062215105341b5ce2c89e

Comment: What specifically you need from the query ? add some brief for your desired results

Comment: you need to specify value for each of them , i mean you can't say `a or b =c` you need to say `a=c or b=c`.

Comment: also if you need both in_date and out_date to be the same day you should change the `OR` to `AND` otherwise only one of them will be date you want and you get duplicates

Comment: I need only result of date 2014-03-10 from two tables. If you look at picture above for results, you will find other different dates in result!!

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake in your query.

You wrote:

```
 WHERE date(attendance_in.EDatetime)   /* wrong! */
    OR date(attendance_out.ODatetime) = "2014-03-10"
```

This is wrong, as the first expression `date(attendance_in.EDatetime)` always evaluates to `true`.

You may want

```
WHERE date(attendance_in.EDatetime) = "2014-03-10"
   OR date(attendance_out.ODatetime) = "2014-03-10"
```

But, this is guaranteed to perform poorly when your attendance_in and attendance_out tables get large, because it will have to scan them; it can't use an index.

You may find that it performs better to write this:

```
WHERE (attendance_in.EDatetime  >='2014-03-10' AND
       attendance_in.EDatetime  < '2014-03-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
   OR (attendance_out.EDatetime >='2014-03-10' AND
       attendance_out.EDatetime < '2014-03-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

That will check whether either the checkin our checkout time occurs on the day in question.

Comment: But result from Attendance_out.ODateTime is not the same date. HERE is the problem. Notice that here in this image for result http://imgbox.com/s9St6B2b